# I want to have a web with videos, should I store them in the database or have it on the front end each video?

Tags: database, web, frontend, backend

My question is like I say above I want to have a web with videos for learning purposes. What will be ideal for this scenario lets say i have 300 videos, should I have them in my front end in an assets folder or that will be make the page slow so other alternative can be have them in the backend and ask for each of them when I need them with an API call. What would you say is the best alternative or if there are other alternatives are welcome to, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is store each video rute in db related with something you want and whatever you want. Anyway you should considerate use youtube or vimeo, both solutions will be cheaper and easier than storing and managing the videos from your back. Good luck ;)

Comment: I haven't think about youtube and vimeo, Thanks

Comment: @FrancoCoronel They are the best choice In my opinion, You're welcome.

Comment: I have another question. Do you know if i use like you said the video route will be visible if someone inspect with chrome dev tools or see the javascript in the page the route. So I mean is not private am I right?

Comment: Exactly, it's not private. Everything you use in your front is going to be visible, if not, the browser could not show it. You could create an API to get the video from js or something but it would be a complex thing to do. Also if you use vimeo or youtube will be visible using your API key. Hope you understand it.

Comment: I understand, I will think which is the the best solution for my case.Thanks for your reply

Comment: @FrancoCoronel You can limit access of Vimeo videos to specific domains: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224819527-Changing-the-privacy-settings-of-your-videos